# rabbitmq consume json message and convert into Java object

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have put together a java test.  It puts a message on a queue and returns it as a string.  What Im trying to achieve is for it to it convert into the java object SignUpDto. I have stripped down the code as much as possible for the question.

**The question:**

How do I modify the test below to convert into a object?

---

**SignUpClass**

```
public class SignUpDto {
    private String customerName;
    private String isoCountryCode;
    ... etc
}
```

**Application - Config class**

```
@Configuration
public class Application  {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {

        // updated with @GaryRussels feedback
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue myQueue() {
        return new Queue("myqueue");
    }
}
```

**The Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
public class TestQueue {

    @Test
    public void convertMessageIntoObject(){

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        AmqpTemplate template = context.getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);

        String jsonString = "{ \"customerName\": \"TestName\", \"isoCountryCode\": \"UK\" }";

        template.convertAndSend("myqueue", jsonString);

        String foo = (String) template.receiveAndConvert("myqueue");

        // this works ok    
        System.out.println(foo);

        // How do I make this convert
        //SignUpDto objFoo = (SignUpDto) template.receiveAndConvert("myqueue");
        // objFoo.toString()  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Configure the `RabbitTemplate` with a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`.

Then use

```
template.convertAndSend("myqueue", myDto);

...

SignUpDto out = (SignUpDto) template.receiveAndConvert("myQueue");
```

Note that the outbound conversion sets up the content type (application/json) and headers with type information that tells the receiving converter what object type to create.

If you really do want to send a simple String of JSON, you need to set the content type to `application/json`. To help the inbound conversion, you can either set the type headers (look at the converter source for information), or you can configure the converter with a `ClassMapper` to determine the type.

**EDIT**

```
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
         message-converter="json" />

<bean id="json"
 class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter" />
```

Or, since you are using Java Config; simply inject one into your template definition.

**EDIT2**

If you want to send a plain JSON string; you need to help the inbound converter via headers.

To set the headers...

```
template.convertAndSend("", "myQueue", jsonString, new MessagePostProcessor() {

    @Override
    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
        message.getMessageProperties().setContentType("application/json");
        message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders()
            .put(AbstractJavaTypeMapper.DEFAULT_CLASSID_FIELD_NAME, "foo.SignUpDto");
        return message;
    }
});
```

Bear in mind, though, that this **sending** template must **NOT** have a JSON message converter (let it default to the `SimpleMessageConverter`). Otherwise, the JSON will be double-encoded.

Comment: how do I configure the RabbitTemplate with a Jackson2JsonMessageConverter?

Comment: im not sure how that xml maps into java config?

Comment: Within your `RabbitTemplate` `@Bean` definition: `template.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());`.

Comment: it now works thanks for your help :-)  I have updated my config settings above so its more readable.  One last question how would I set the type headers.

Comment: See the second edit - beware of the caveat at the end, though.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for this great answer.